# Android Studio - Building library aar file doesn't append flavor or buildType to output

Tags: android-studio, gradle, android-library, android-module

I am running assemble for my library module , I see from logs that it should generate two files  `myLib-release.aar` and `myLib-debug.aar` inside the `myLib/build/outputs/` folder.

However, I always only find one lib there that is `myLib.aar`, it doesn't matter if I run `assemble` for both, `assembleDbug` or `assembleRelease`.

Why is this happening?

Answer (score 0):

According to this discussion it is an error (or planned feature) in gradle, up to date it is still the same.

https://github.com/gradle/gradle/issues/8328

Workaround can be to implement this:

```
// in library/library.gradle
afterEvaluate {
    def debugFile = file("$buildDir/outputs/aar/library.aar")
    tasks.named("assembleDebug").configure {
        doLast {
            debugFile.renameTo("$buildDir/outputs/aar/library-debug.aar")
        }
    }
    tasks.named("assembleRelease").configure {
        doLast {
            debugFile.renameTo("$buildDir/outputs/aar/library-release.aar")
        }
    }
}
```

You may then implement copy tasks as desired.